# Trying to connect to gitlab api with azureAD access_token

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, gitlab, azure-active-directory

(Warning: french user, please forgive me in case of bad translation)

I'm currently trying to call gitlab api with an Oauth access_token header generate by AzureAD, starting with this how-to : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/azure.html

I generate an access token throught postman 
[with this configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33y0C.png)
and i get an acess token with it, but when i call gitlab api with this access_token in a Bearer header i have a 401 unauthorized

For information, the configuration of my tenant, app_id and secret_id are correctly set in my gitlab.rb, and i can connect succesfully [throught this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOZG8.png)

I'm just not sure what scope are needed, so i create one in azure.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have experience with Gitlab but it looks like you are only configuring a user authentication method. It won't be used by the API, only the UI.

Comment: You'd need to configure JSON Web Token authentication on Gitlab to accept tokens from AAD and I don't know if that is possible to configure.

Comment: Ok so i'm trying with https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/jwt.html but with the same result

Comment: @seb barre You could also take a look on this thread https://serverfault.com/questions/923996/sso-between-gitlab-and-azure-ad-doesnt-work

Comment: my azure configuration works fine, actually, if i connect throught UI. The problem is when i use the access_token generated by azure to request gitlab api.

Comment: @juunas This error usually happens when user wanted to access API endpoint without required permission , But i am wondering for his case I guess on azure portal nothing to permit, what do you think? Though I am trying to get into this.